# vb.net assign image to picturebox through panel controls

Tags: vb.net, image, panel, picturebox

I'm writing a program of a card game in VB.NET. 
I have encountered a problem. Computer_Flow is declared like System.Windows.Forms.Panel manualy on design window. I have created a picture box like this programmaticly:

```
Dim P As PictureBox = New PictureBox  
P.Size = New Point(Cards_Width, Cards_Height)  
P.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage  
P.Image = Image.FromFile(Images_Folder_Path & "Back.png")   
P.Tag = Deck(DI)    
P.Margin = New Padding(1)  
Computers_Hand(DI) = Deck(DI)  
Computer_Flow.Controls.Add(P)
```

Later on I want to change that PictureBox image. I'm trying to change it like that:

```
Computer_Flow.Controls(i).image = Image.FromFile(Images_Folder_Path & "Back.png")
```

But I get an error which says: 'image' is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.Control'.

Who can help me to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `cast` that `control` to `picture box` in order to get your result.
Try this out,

```
CType(Computer_Flow.Controls(i),PictureBox).image=Image.FromFile(Images_Folder_Path & "Back.png")
```

### [CType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x2877xb%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

***EDIT:***

you can easily avoid that `invalidCastException` in an effective manner like this,

```
If TypeOf Computer_Flow.Controls(i) Is PictureBox then

CType(Computer_Flow.Controls(i),PictureBox).image=Image.FromFile(Images_Folder_Path & "Back.png")

End If
```

### [TypeOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, that works great as well as other answer, I think this is even better, cause I don't need to declare other variable. Thanks!

Comment: For the record, you do avoid a temporary variable, which is good, but `CType` will throw an `InvalidCastException` if the `Control` you give it happens not to be a PictureBox. In this case, I'd wrap it in a `Try...Catch` block.

Comment: @GriphoN if you want to overcome the exception which was mentioned by solarbear, you can try my new edit.

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing a list of `Control`, a base class which does not contain an `Image` member.

You'll need to typecast it as a `PictureBox`:

```
Dim pb As PictureBox = TryCast(Computer_Flow.Controls(i), PictureBox)

If Not pb Is Nothing Then
     pb.image = Image.FromFile(Images_Folder_Path & "Back.png")
End If
```

That way VB will know it really isn't just a `Control` but a `PictureBox`, with an `Image` member. I suggest adding the `TryCast`, just in case.